# Is it possible to create Radial scrolling UV motion without scaling?

Tags: animation, uv

Inorder to show the winddirection in a turbine animation, the UVs (parented empties with  a UV wrap modifier) are to be scrolled radially .

Scaling the empties does provide radial motion **but it scales them as well**.

Is it possible to create radial scrolling motion without scaling?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outside of a circle has more surface area then the center so no, what you are asking for is impossible. But you could move some individual elements out to show the motion.

One easy way to do this would be to use actual objects and move them by scaling multiple objects from the center with Only Locations toggled on:

[image]

Or you could also use particles to achieve some cool effects communicating the flow nicely, but further advice requires more info about your situation than you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,which particle flow effect are you talking about?

Comment: The number of effects you can achieve with particles is not finite so I don't think the word "which" is suitable here. You would need to imagine what kind of effect you want and then make it with particles.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to say in detail without knowing exactly what you need, but some variation on this might serve your purpose:

[image]

Here, the nodes are being used to control simple color bands, keying the offset on *Length*, but they could be used to control the UV look-up of a suitably mapped texture, for hand-drawn, or other effects

[image]

Comment: Oops, backwards .. but that can be flipped easily enough :)

Comment: cannot...look....away....

Comment: @MattCoubrough   Your mouse..... is .... irresistibly ... drawn .. to the little.. triangle.. on the left of the answ.,,, NO! NO! NOT THAT ONE!